# Jersey + Grizzly behind Apache reverse proxy - Resource not found

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, jersey-2.0, grizzly

I am having a jersey based REST Application which is running on grizzly and configured it as follows behind an apache reverse proxy
e.g. `www.example.com/base/json/helloworld/get` should redirect to my REST service. (Multiple Resources). However, when I try to open the url in the browser I always get a Resource not found.

In my apache config:

```
ProxyPass /base/ http://localhost:8123/
ProxyPassReverse /base/ "http://localhost:8123/
```

My grizzly server configuration is really simple and works if I do a curl request: curl `localhost:8123/base/json/helloworld/get` => Response is correct.
However,  if I acess the url in my browser, e.g. 
`example.com/base/json/helloworld` I am getting the grizzly error:

Resource identified by path /json/helloworld/get', does not exist.

```
 HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(http://localhost:8123/base), resourceConfig, false);
```

Am I missing something? I already tried changing the url to the domain and so on, but I can't get my head around why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found my fault. In the grizzly server my url was configured with the path /base/, but the Proxy Pass did not include the /base/ path at the end of the url. Now it works fine.